# Prestashop add a token to ajax file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, module, prestashop

I tried sending to my module prestashop addons. I got a message "Technical validation has been declined". This message contain the

**You need to add a token to your ajax file.**

My ajax script is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post", 
        url : "../modules/priceupdate/ajax-call.php",
        data: "ajax=ps_ajax_update_prices",
        success : function(response){
            $('#update-ajaxresponse').html(response)
        }
    });
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the token are declared by PrestaShop, you should to add only the token in your `data`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post", 
    url : "../modules/priceupdate/ajax-call.php",
    data: "ajax=ps_ajax_update_prices&token=" + token ,
    success : function(response){
        $('#update-ajaxresponse').html(response)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, am i need a control for token in ajax-call.php?

Comment: @user5510975 Obviously! It's to prevent CSRF attack. Server side you can use Tools::getToken(), see the specs in the class because at the moment I don't remember.